# Is it illegal to sell 'sex novelty sweets' in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

With regards to the current investigation into American Candy stores in Westminster, UK for tax avoidance, other alleged offences are also apparently being investigated:

> 450 vapes which exceeded nicotine allowances were also taken. Among
> tax offences the Council is also investigating whether the shops have:
>
> - sold out of date food
> - **sold sex novelty sweets**
> - counterfeit “Wonka” bars, and
> - possibly breached Covid-19 opening conditions.

Source: https://www.mylondon.news/news/zone-1-news/oxford-streets-american-candy-shops-24192552

Is selling 'sex novelty sweets' really a specific offense in the UK?

Comment: Considering it's a local council investigation, it may be a breach of a local byelaw or trading licence. These are nigh on impossible to trace without further details

Comment: I think what you mean is tax evasion when you say tax avoidance.

Comment: Freedom of information to Westminster council